# Accessing a route directly without accessing root

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I try to access a route like `www.deployedWebApp.com/profiles` I get a 404, bu when I access the root `www.deployedWebApp.com/` and then click in the profiles button that pushes to `/profiles` it works. I suppose that it only loads the routes in the root `/` because the code for this route is at `App.js` but this can lead to poor UX due to sending the direct route `www.deployedWebApp.com/profiles` for a friend and getting a 404, so is there a way to fix this without a Back-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to fix this issue dependent on your deployment method.

1. [Deploying Static Server Using Serve](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#static-server) `serve -s build -l port`.

As `-s, --single` Rewrite all not-found requests to `index.html`. Other options mentioned here also [Building for Relative Paths](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths)

2. Using firebase, you can use this option `Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? (y/N)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with GitHub pages, where I was hosting, when switching to firebase it works like a charm